# How to calculate baud rate and determine the number of stop bits in asynchronous serial

Tags: serial, baudrate

Below is the given question:
[image]

For my understanding, **1/baud_rate** = 104.16
However, when I tried to do reverse division, the result is so different than expected.

1. My calculation to find baud rate:
   **1/104.16 =9.6006 *  10^-3**

Is my calculation of baud rate wrong?

2.How do I determine the number of stop bits in this case?

Comment: The link just provides some dark blue background page, without it I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Any receiver can handle the specified number of stop bits or arbitrarily more.  Almost all modern UARTS only need one stop bit on receive.  Sending out 2 is occasionally used to pace data but is a RARE need after the days of Teletype terminals, paper tapes punches and primitive protocol converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baud rate is \$\dfrac{1}{104.16\times 10^{-6}}\$ = 9600.6 bits per second.

> How do I determine the number of stop bits in this case?

It looks like 2 stop bits on the example you give but it could also be regarded as 1 stop bit and an indeterminate idling period.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the prefix. It's not 104.15 s, it's 104.16 **u**s. So 1/(104.16 us) = 9.60061 kHz. Because 9600 baud is a very common baud rate, I'd round to that.

Your second question is more murky. You appear to have marked the last bit as the stop bit, which I think is correct, because the next bit period is marked as idle. So it would appear that the stop bit length is 1 stop bit. In general, however, without knowing the length of the stop bit, you can't figure it out from a scope trace because you can't differentiate between the stop bit and the line idling.